# How to fetch values from starting of the year in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2016

I can get exact 3 years of value with the below code (from 01/24/2018 - 01/25/2021)

```
select * from datamining.dbo.EmployeeDetails
where DateOfjoining >= DATEADD(year,-3,GETDATE())
```

But I'm expecting **the results should be from 01/01/2018 - 01/25/2021(Till date)**

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Get the current year, subtract 3, then use datefromparts.

Comment: And perhaps time to learn the [date functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) available in tsql by reading the documentation. You could also use datepart to get the day of the year, subtract [that value - 1] from the current date and then subtract 3 years from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways.  One is to combine YEAR, which extracts the numeric year value from a date and DATEFROMPARTS, which constructs a date from Year, Month, and Day componenets.  EG:

```
select * from datamining.dbo.EmployeeDetails
where DateOfjoining >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(year,-3,GETDATE())),1,1)
```

Comment: This really worked. I would love to learn more of this. Thankyou